# Plotting y values of an arc

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, math

I am trying to plot the segment of a circle (2D) as an arc in matplotlib.  I have written a class which will provide the maths for the segment such as chord length, height of arc etc.  I wish to plot the x y values between (0,0) and (0, chord length).

I am currently representing the X values as numpy linspace array (0, chordLength, 200).  I am a bit stumped as to how to plot the y values as a similar linspace array so that I can plot these points using matplotlib.  The idea behind this is to display the curvature of the earth between two points of a known arc length (great circle distance).  I have been reading around sine cosine etc however outside of using cookie cutter formulas for my geometry calculations, I am somewhat lost as to how to apply it to gain my y values.

First, the circle class

```py
import numpy as np

class Circle:

    def __init__(self,radiusOfCircle,lengthOfArc):
        self.radius = radiusOfCircle
        self.circumference = 2 * np.pi * self.radius
        self.diameter = self.radius * 2
        self.arcLength = lengthOfArc
        self.degrees = self.calcDegrees()
        self.radians = self.calcRadians()
        self.chordLength = self.calcChordLength()
        self.sagitta = self.calcSagitta()
        self.segmentArea = self.calcSegmentArea()
        self.arcHeight = self.calcArcHeight()

    #Setters and getters for the Circle class (TODO: setters)
    def getRadius(self):
        return self.radius

    def getCircumference(self):
        return self.circumference

    def getDiameter(self):
        return self.diameter

    def getArcLength(self):
        return self.arcLength

    def getRadians(self):
        return self.radians

    def getDegrees(self):
        return self.degrees

    def getChordLength(self):
        return self.chordLength

    def getSagitta(self):
        return self.sagitta

    def getSegmentArea(self):
        return self.segmentArea

    def getArcHeight(self):
        return self.arcHeight

    #Define Circle class methods

    #Calculate the central angle, in degrees, by using the arcLength
    def calcDegrees(self):
        self.degrees = (self.arcLength / (np.pi * self.diameter)) * 360 #Gives angle in degrees at centre of the circle between the two points (beginning and end points of arcLength)
        return self.degrees

    #Calculate the central angle in radians, between two points on the circle
    def calcRadians(self):#Where theta is the angle between both points at the centre of the circle
        self.radians = np.radians(self.degrees) # Convert degrees to radians to work with ChordLength formula
        return self.radians

    #Returns the chord lengths of the arc, taking theta (angle in radians) as it's argument
    #The chord is the horizontal line which separates the arc segment from the rest of the circle
    def calcChordLength(self):
        self.chordLength = 2*self.radius*np.sin(self.radians/2) #formula works for theta (radians) only, not degrees #confirmed using http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Sphere/Arc_.htm
        return self.chordLength

    #Calculates the length of arc, taking theta (angle in radians) as its argument.
    def calcArcLength(self):
        self.arcLength = (self.degrees/360)*self.diameter*np.pi #confirmed using http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Sphere/Arc_.htm
        return self.arcLength

    #Calculates the sagitta of the arc segment.  The sagitta is the horizontal line which extends from the bottom
    #of the circle to the chord of the segment
    def calcSagitta(self):
        self.sagitta = self.radius - (np.sqrt((self.radius**2)-((self.chordLength/2)**2))) #Confirmed correct against online calculator https://www.liutaiomottola.com/formulae/sag.htm
        return self.sagitta

    #Calculates the area of the circular segment/arc).
    def calcSegmentArea(self):
        self.segmentArea = (self.radians - np.sin(self.radians) / 2) * self.radius**2
        return self.segmentArea

    #Calculate the height of the arc
    #Radius - sagitta of the segment
    def calcArcHeight(self):
        self.arcHeight = self.radius - self.sagitta
        return self.arcHeight
```

I have not progressed very far with the main program as one of the first tasks im aiming to do is create the y values.   This is what I have so far -

```py
from circle import Circle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    #define centre point

    #Circle(radius,arc length)
    c1 = Circle(3440.065,35) #Nautical miles radius with 35Nm arc length
    chordLength = c1.getChordLength()
    arcHeight = c1.getArcHeight()

    centerX = chordLength/2
    centerY = 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For context, I wish to use this 'arc' to add elevation data to, akin to - https://link.ui.com/#.  I hope to simulate increased curvature over distance which I can use for rough line of sight analysis.

However, first step is getting the y values.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by this: I wish to plot the x y values between (0,0) and (0, chord length)

Comment: Essentially I would like the start of the arc, on the left side, to start at 0, 0 and the arc to rise and fall akin to the curvature of the earth as seen in the graphs produced here -  https://link.ui.com/# note the height of the arc increasing as the distance is increased.

Comment: I don't see an arc at that website. Could you provide an image or some instructions to see such an arc?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/322c0bfb18693854c66afe2446f7fe3f.png 

Hope that works, the graph I'm referring to is at the bottom of the screen, the closer the distance between the two points the lesser the 'curve' and the further the distance the more pronounced it is.

I ultimately want to plot individual points as I will be layering elevation data along those points for line of sight analysis.

Comment: If you answer your own question, don't change the question, but post it as an answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Thanks, will do! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final solution, I'm not 100% about the maths and how it all works but if anyone is struggling with the same problem - I hope this helps.

The circle class can be found in the original question, located below. Find attached the final code which provides me with what I was after - simulating the curvature of the earth on a graph based upon the arc length (great circle distance).

Big thank you to all who took the time to answer me and help me along my way.

```
from circle import Circle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def calcStartAngle(startY,centreY,startX,centreX):
    startAngle = np.arctan2(startY-centreY, startX-centreX)
    return startAngle

def calcEndAngle(endY,centreY,endX,centreX):
    endAngle = np.arctan2(endY-centreY, endX-centreX)
    return endAngle

def main():
    distance = 200
    radius = 3440.065

#create circle object
c1 = Circle(radius,distance)
angle = c1.getDegrees()
xc = c1.getXc()
yc = c1.getYc()

#set start and end points
x1,y1 = 0,0
x2,y2 = distance,0

#get start and end angles
startAngle = calcStartAngle(y1,yc,x1,xc)
endAngle = calcEndAngle(y2,yc,x2,xc)
angleList = np.linspace(startAngle,endAngle,distance)
x_values = np.linspace(x1,x2,distance)
y_valuesList = []

for i in range(len(x_values)):
    y = radius*np.sin(angleList[i]) - c1.getArcHeight()
    y_valuesList.append(y)

#Create numpy array to hold y values
y_values = np.array(y_valuesList)

plt.ylim(0,50)
plt.plot(x_values,y_values)
plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Here is an example of the finished product -

[image: finished plot]